# Problems with Nth in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm trying to write a function that can calculate GPA. Now I can do limited calculation(only 3 ),but I stuck on how to calculate more , without using loop or recursion (that's the requirement of subject)  how to expend nth function? like: (nth n) ,if so ,is that mean i need to write a lambda expression? As an newbie, I maynot describe the question clearly, really need some help..

**Glist** is grade points **Clist** is credit hours.

GPA=( gradepoint *credithour + gradepoint *credithour) **/** ( the sum of credithour)  like: (3*1+3*2+4*1)/(1+2+1)

here is my code:

```
(defun gpa (Glist Clist)
     (format t "~3,2f~%" 
      (/ 
        (+(nth 0 (mapcar #' * Glist Clist))
          (nth 1 (mapcar #' * Glist Clist))
          (nth 2 (mapcar #' * Glist Clist)))
        (+ (nth 0 Clist)
           (nth 1 Clist)
           (nth 2 Clist))
                   );end "/"
                   );end "format" 
       (values)    );end
```

Comment: Use standard indentation, and do not duplicate code to comment your parentheses (I mean, what the hell?).  See for example: http://gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `nth` to traverse a list, you're doing it wrong. In this case, you might want to write a summing function:

```
(defun sum (items)
  (reduce #'+ items))
```

Comment: @Rainer: Thanks! Updated. (I'm actually a Schemer, so I'm sometimes unaware of the "better way" to do things in CL. Though, in Scheme I'd use `reduce` too (it takes different arguments from the CL version though), so.)

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

This seems like a good opportunity to emphasize some common (little c) Lisp ideas, so I fleshed out my answer to illustrate.

---

As mentioned in another answer, you could use a `sum` function that operates on lists (of numbers):

```
(defun sum (nums)
  (reduce #'+ nums))
```

The dot product is the multiplicative sum of two (equal-length) vectors:

```
(defun dot-product (x y)
  (sum (mapcar #'* x y)))
```

The function `gpa` is a simple combination of the two:

```
(defun gpa (grades credits)
  (/ (dot-product grades credits) (sum credits)))
```

The example from the question results in the answer we expect (minus being formatted as a float):

```
(gpa '(3 3 4) '(1 2 1))
> 13/4
```

---

There are a few things worth mentioning from this example:

1. You should learn about [`map`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_map.htm), [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm), and their variants and relatives.  These functions are very important to Lisp and are very useful for operating on lists.  `map*` functions generally map sequences to a sequence, and `reduce` usually transforms a sequence into to a single value (you can however use forms like `(reduce #'cons '(1 2 3))`).
2. This is a good example of the "bottom-up" approach to programming; by programming simple functions like `sum` that are often useful, you make it easy to write `dot-product` on top of it. Now the `gpa` function is a simple, readable function built on top of the other two.  These are all one-liners, and all are easily readable to anyone who has a basic knowledge of CL.  This is in contrast to the methodology usually applied to OOP.
3. There is no repetition of code.  Sure, `sum` is used more than once, but only where it makes sense.  You can do very little more to abstract the notion of a sum of the elements of a list. It's more natural in Scheme to write functions with functions, and that's a whole different topic.  This is a simple example, but no two functions are doing the same thing.

Comment: ohhhh that's really simple. why I didn't find this function.. anyway , thanks for help. I have to read more carefully..

Comment: +1 Very nice with the "bottom-up" approach explanation. I wrote a similar type of answer, albeit less eloquently ;-), and for Scheme, quite recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313563/flatten-a-list-using-only-the-forms-in-the-little-schemer/7324493#7324493 And yes, the conclusion is that `reduce` (or `fold` in Scheme) is a very important operation. :-D

Comment: Ah, I don't think I ever knew how to do a `foldr` in CL...by following my own link I figured it out, this was the example I wanted to use above: `(reduce #'cons <list> :initial-value '() :from-end t) ==> <list>`.  [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function) neatly shows how this is the identity function on lists, it just has clunky syntax in CL.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for that link, I don't use Lisps too often, it was instructive.