# Scheme function that sum number u and list x u+x1+x2

Tags: lisp, scheme, tail-recursion

Im new to Scheme and trying to make function that is (in f u x), u is integer, x is a list and f binary function. The scheme expression (in + 3 '(1 2 3)) should return 3+1+2+3=9.

I have this but if i do (in + 3 '(1 2)) it return 3 not 6. What am i doing wrong?

```
(define (in f u x)
  (define (h x u)
    (if (null? x)
        u
        (h (cdr x) (f u (car x)))))
  (h x 0))
```

Comment: I recommend commenting your code. Then it would be easy to compare the comments with what the code actually does to see where it went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of what your `in` function is supposed to do, you can define it this way:

```
(define in fold)   ; after loading SRFI 1
```

:-P

(More seriously, you can look at [my implementation of `fold`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313563/flatten-a-list-using-only-the-forms-in-the-little-schemer/7324493#7324493) for some ideas, but you should submit your own version for homework.)

Comment: Thanku, i will not copy paste you solution, not what i do, just wanted to see if any one could give me hint or give me ideas of how i can solve this problem. You did Thanks.