# List manipulation in Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten a list using only the forms in “The Little Schemer”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313563/flatten-a-list-using-only-the-forms-in-the-little-schemer)

I simply want to turn '(a b (c d) e) into '(a b c d e) 
(i.e., insert each member of the inner list into the outer list, while maintaining the order of the elements).

There has to be a simple way to do this, but it eludes me for some reason.

Comment: Spoiler: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7324493/13. (If this is for homework, please don't read that thread until you've tried solving it first!)

Answer (score 0):

You see that '(a b (c d) e) is a tree, don't you? Something like

```
a---b
|\--c--d
 \--e
```

In this representation, nodes are lists, and leafs are symbols.
What you could do, it print all the leafs of the tree:

1. if the tree is empty (= is the empty list), then stop
2. If the tree is not empty, then

   1. If the tree's CAR is a symbol, print it, then process the CDR of the tree
   2. If the tree's CAR is a list, process the CAR of the tree, then process the CDR o the tree

Once you do that, you'll replace "print" by "put the value somewhere". Hopefully, that should lead you to what you want.