# Racket/Scheme Flatten Explanations

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, flatten

Can someone help me to break down exactly the order of execution for the following versions of flatten?  I'm using Racket.

version 1, is from racket itself, while version two is a more common? implementation.

```
(define (flatten1 list)
  (let loop ([l list] [acc null])
    (printf "l = ~a acc = ~a\n" l acc)
    (cond [(null? l) acc]
          [(pair? l) (loop (car l) (loop (cdr l) acc))]
          [else (cons l acc)])))

(define (flatten2 l)
  (printf "l = ~a\n" l)
  (cond [(null? l) null]
        [(atom? l) (list l)]
        [else (append (flatten2 (car l)) (flatten2 (cdr l)))]))
```

Now, running the first example with '(1 2 3) produces:

```
l = (1 2 3) acc = ()
l = (2 3) acc = ()
l = (3) acc = ()
l = () acc = ()
l = 3 acc = ()
l = 2 acc = (3)
l = 1 acc = (2 3)
'(1 2 3)
```

while the second produces:

```
l = (1 2 3)
l = 1
l = (2 3)
l = 2
l = (3)
l = 3
l = ()
'(1 2 3)
```

The order of execution seems different.  In the first example, it looks like the second loop `(loop (cdr l) acc)` is firing before the first loop since '(2 3) is printing right away.  Whereas in the second example, 1 prints before the '(2 3), which seems like the first call to flatten inside of append is evaluated first.

I'm going through the Little Schemer but these are more difficult examples that I could really use some help on.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is this:

- `flatten1` works by storing the output elements (first from the `cdr` side, then from the `car` side) into an accumulator. This works because lists are built from right to left, so working on the `cdr` side first is correct.
- `flatten2` works by recursively flattening the `car` and `cdr` sides, then `append`ing them together.

`flatten1` is faster, especially if the tree is heavy on the `car` side: the use of an accumulator means that there is no extra list copying, no matter what. Whereas, the `append` call in `flatten2` causes the left-hand side of the `append` to be copied, which means lots of extra list copying if the tree is heavy on the `car` side.

So in summary, I would consider `flatten2` a beginner's implementation of flatten, and `flatten1` a more polished, professional version. See also [my implementation of flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324493/13), which works using the same principles as `flatten1`, but using a left-fold instead of the right-fold that `flatten1` uses.

(A left-fold solution uses less stack space but potentially more heap space. A right-fold solution uses more stack and usually less heap, though a quick read of `flatten1` suggests in this case that the heap usage is about the same as my implementation.)

Comment: Thanks.  But why does (loop (cdr l)) fire before (loop (car l)) in example one, whereas (flatten2 (car l)) fires before (flatten2 (cdr l)) in example 2?

Comment: So, in `flatten1`, `cdr` goes before `car` for the reason I described: the accumulator list is built from right to left. In `flatten2`, the order doesn't matter, but Racket always uses left-to-right order when evaluating expressions, so that's why you see `car` before `cdr` here.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So in Racket, lists (cons) are built right to left but expressions are evaluated left to right.  That helps.

Comment: In all Scheme systems, lists are always built from right to left, but the order of evaluation for subexpressions is unspecified (meaning that different implementations are allowed to use whatever order pleases them). The Racket developers made a conscious decision to always use left-to-right evaluation; other Scheme implementations may exhibit a different (and not necessarily deterministic) order.

Comment: Initially, I thought that the calls to loop in flatten1 should also be evaluated left to right, but the main cause of my confusion was that the second call to loop IS the second parameter of the first call to loop, so therefore the second loop evaluates first, whereas the second call to flatten2 is an independent parameter of append, and so fires after the first param is eval'ed.

Comment: Correction, they are of course still evaluated left to right, I meant printed left before right.

Answer (score 5):

Not really an answer to your question (Chris provided an excellent answer already!), but for completeness' sake here's yet another way to implement `flatten`, similar to `flatten2` but a bit more concise:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (null? x))
       (not (pair? x))))

(define (flatten lst)
  (if (atom? lst)
      (list lst)
      (apply append (map flatten lst))))
```

And another way to implement the left-fold version (with more in common to `flatten1`), using standard Racket procedures:

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (define (loop lst acc)
    (if (atom? lst)
        (cons lst acc)
        (foldl loop acc lst)))
  (reverse (loop lst '())))
```