# Inserting into a Binary Tree in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, binary-tree

I am wondering how to insert elements from a list into a binary search tree. I am wondering why the following code does not work as I expected. The output is **'((4 1 5 13 6) () ())**   My next problem is going to be sorting the elements in the list, but for now I just want to insert them.

Is my output correct for the problem I stated? My code is as follows:

```
( define ( make-tree value left right ) 
( list value left right ))
( define ( value tree ) ( car tree ))
( define ( left tree ) ( cadr tree ))
( define ( right tree ) ( caddr tree ))

(define (insert-list L T)
 (cond ((null? T) (make-tree L '() '()))
    ((= (car L) (value T)) T)
    ((< (car L) (value T)) (make-tree (value T)
                                      (insert-list (car L) (left T))
                                      (right T)))
    ((> (car L) (value T)) (make-tree (value T)
                                      (left T)
                                      (insert-list (car L) (right T))))))
```

Comment: How do you call this function?  You showed some output, but what was the input?  It's not immediately clear what you're _trying_ to do.  Since you're comparing `(car L)` with the value of `T`,  it looks like you're trying to insert the _first_ element of `L` into `T`, but then your recursive calls are being made with `(car L)`, not `L`.  What are you _trying_ to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem with this code

When writing recursive code, it's typically a good idea to consider what the function is supposed to take as arguments, and what it should return, as well as what the base case is.

```
(define (insert-list L T)
 (cond
    ((null? T) (make-tree L '() '()))                                     ; case 1
    ((= (car L) (value T)) T)                                             ; case 2
    ((< (car L) (value T)) (make-tree (value T)                           ; case 3
                                      (insert-list (car L) (left T))
                                      (right T)))
    ((> (car L) (value T)) (make-tree (value T)                           ; case 4
                                      (left T)
                                      (insert-list (car L) (right T))))))
```

Based on your description, `insert-list` is supposed to take a list of elements and a tree, and return the tree that you'd get from inserting those elements into the tree, one after another.  Does this code actually do that?  There are a few cases:

1. When the tree is null, you do need to create a new tree with some element, but your first case creates a tree with the *whole* list as its element, and returns this.  This is why you get a result like  `((4 1 5 13 6) () ())`.  You got to this base case and returned the result of `(make-tree L '() '()))`.
2. When the *first* element of the list is the value of the tree, then you're right to return the tree, since you don't need to do anything else to insert that *first* element of the list.  But then you don't do anything else with the rest of the elements.  That doesn't do any good.  If you had a test case like `(insert-list '(2 3 4) '(2 () ()))`, you'd see that the return value would be `(2 () ())`.
3. (and 4.)  In these cases you make a recursive call like `(insert-list (car L) (left T))`, but this doesn't make sense, because the first argument to `insert-list` is supposed to be a list of elements, and you're calling it with `(car L)` which is a single element.  You're right, though, in recognizing that `(car L)` needs to be inserted into the left subtree of the tree, and you're constructing it correctly, if only you were calling `(insert-element (car L) (left T))`, instead.  However, you're still not doing anything with the *rest* of the elements afterward.

#### Folds to the rescue!

If you're trying to take a list of numbers and insert the *first* one into a tree to get a new tree, then insert the second number into that tree, and so on, you're looking for something like this pseudo-code:

```
tree = initial-tree
for element in list 
  tree = insert(element,tree)
return tree
```

This kind of operation is typically represented functionally by a `fold`.  I've described folds in some detail in an answer to [Flattening a List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19229444/1281433), and there's lots of information about them out there.  The idea is that you want to turn something like

```
(insert-list '(4 1 5 13 6) '())
```

into

```
(tree-insert (tree-insert (tree-insert (tree-insert (tree-insert '() 4) 1) 5) 13) 6)
```

and that's a *left-associative* fold. Let's use this definition of `foldl`:

```
(define (foldl fn init list)
  (if (null? list)
      init
      (foldl fn (fn init (car list)) (cdr list))))
```

In this particular case, you'd need to implement your normal `tree-insert` function that takes a tree and an element a returns a new tree, and then your function to insert *all* the elements from a list is simply

```
(lambda (tree elements)
  (foldl tree-insert tree elements))
```

For instance,

```
> (foldl tree-insert '() '(3 5 8 1 9))
(3 (1 () ()) (5 () (8 () (9 () ()))))
> (foldl tree-insert '() '(5 8 2 3 1 6 9))
(5 (2 (1 () ()) (3 () ())) (8 (6 () ()) (9 () ())))
> (foldl tree-insert '() '(4 1 5 13 6))             ; the test from the question
(4 (1 () ()) (5 () (13 (6 () ()) ())))
```