# List of lists to normal list in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to make a scheme function that returns a 'normal' list from a pair made by lists of lists.

I'm trying to change something like this:

```
((((((() 1) 2) 3) 4) (12 13 14)) ((((() 8) 9) 10) 11) (5 6 7))
```

into something like this:

```
(1 2 3 4 12 13 14 8 9 10 11 5 6 7)
```

I've tried using tail recursion, but my code just returns the same initial pair.

Then I did this, but it also doesn't work and kind of shuffles the list:

```
(define (tolist l1 lista)
   (if (empty? (cdr lista))
        null
        (if (empty? (car lista))
            (append l1 (cdr lista))
            (tolist (append l1 (car lista)) (list (cdr lista)) ))))
```

What can I do?

Comment: Every list consists of pairs. eg `(1 2 3)` is really the structure  `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))`. Is it [`flatten`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313563/flatten-a-list-using-only-the-forms-in-the-little-schemer) you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oscar Lopez has given you a good answer, although I would test l1 with list? rather than pair?, as with his code (flatten '(1 . 2)) would produce (1 2), which is probably not your desired result.

With that correction his code can be turned into a fold:

```
(define (flatten seq)
  (letrec ((flatten-with-append
             (lambda (elt acc) ;; args as for SRFI-1 fold
               (if (list? elt)
                   (fold flatten-with-append acc elt)
                   (append acc (list elt))))))
    (flatten-with-append seq '())))
```

One problem with this way of doing it is that it appends, which is not very efficient.  It is usually better to cons into the accumulator and then reverse.  This would be likely to be more optimal:

```
(define (flatten seq)
  (letrec ((flatten-with-cons
             (lambda (elt acc) ;; args as for SRFI-1 fold
               (if (list? elt)
                   (fold flatten-with-cons acc elt)
                   (cons elt acc)))))
    (reverse (flatten-with-cons seq '()))))
```

Comment: Just for fun, I added another very efficient implementation to my answer, one that does not use folding procedures. Also, I prefer to use `pair?` because `list?` is very inefficient, every time it has to traverse the whole list just to check if it's a proper list. And it's unlikely that OP expects to pass improper lists as arguments, this looks like a learning exercise...

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpfull :D